# How to set customView in UITableViewCell with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have UITableView, UITablaViewCell, CustomView

and UITableViewCell includes customView.

I'm trying to put Product's data to cell with my function not cellForRowAt.

Cell shows just origin view ProductView.xib with empty data

Please help.

ViewController.swift

```
struct Product {
    let brand: String
    let product: String
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell
    // this line is not work
    // productView is not update
    cell.productView = createProductView(product: product)
    return cell
}
    
func createProductView(product: Product) -> ProductView {
    let productView = ProductView()
    productView.brandLabel.text = product.brand
    productView.productLabel.text = product.product
    return productView
}
```

UITableViewCell.swift

```
class ProductTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var productView: ProductView!
}
```

ProductView.swift

```
class ProductView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var productView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var brandLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productLabel: UILabel!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

private func commonInit(){
    let bundle = Bundle(for: ProductView.self)
    bundle.loadNibNamed("ProductView", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(productView)
    productView.frame = self.bounds
}
```

Comment: can you share the error message or crash log if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code

**Issue 1:** `cellForRowAt IndexPath` gets called multiple times, with your code you will end up creating a new `ProductView` every time tableView is scrolled (cell is reused). instead you can create product view only once and update its label every time cell is reused

**Issue 2:** In `ProductView`'s commonInit you set the frame using `productView.frame = self.bounds` self.bounds will always be(0,0,0,0). Because you have instantiated ProductView as  `ProductView()`

**Issue 3:** `createProductView` is supposed to return an instance of `ProductView` hence the method signature is invalid  so you should change it from `func createProductView(product: Product) -> ProductView()` to `func createProductView(product: Product) -> ProductView` as already suggested in answer above

**What can be better solution?**

```
class ProductTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var productView: ProductView!

    func updateProductView(product: Product) {
        productView.brandLabel.text = product.brand
        productView.productLabel.text = product.product
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        productView.brandLabel.text = nil
        productView.productLabel.text = nil
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.productView = createProductView()
        self.addSubview(self.productView)
        self.productView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.productView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            self.productView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
            self.productView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            self.productView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }


    func createProductView() -> ProductView {
        return ProductView()
    }
}
```

Finally in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell

    //assuming you already have a product for index path
    cell.updateProductView(product: product)
    return cell
}
```

**EDIT:**

As OP is facing issue with loading nib from bundle updating the answer here.

In your `ProductView` common init change the way you access bundle from
`Bundle(for: ProductView.self)` to `Bundle.main` as shown below

```
class ProductView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var productView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var brandLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productLabel: UILabel!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

private func commonInit(){
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ProductView", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(productView)
}
```

Few things to take care

1. Ensure you have an XIB named `ProductView` in your bundle
2. Ensure you have set its file owner to `ProductView`

Comment: thanks for your comment! i tested your solution, but occurred Unexpectedly found nil from self.addSubview(self.productView) in awakeFromNib(), and how to solve Issue 2??